# Fault connector not called on Delete using flow

Tags: visual-workflow, fault-connector

I have a flow to delete the account relationship records when a parent account field is removed from an account. The problem is it throws an exception when there are no records. I can solve this by getting the records into a collection (using Get Record) and then deleting it if the collection size is greater than 0.

But why the fault isn't working? ( as mentioned in the [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdmfNUAR/flow-error-when-delete-records-doesnt-find-records))

**Error**
[image: Error after fault.]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to suppress the error by adding a decision in the fault path with two empty branches (I just checked for the value of Flow.FaultMessage, but don't do anything with it).